# Non-existent category url works with "Shop base with category"

Tags: wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, permalinks, canonical-link

I set "Shop base with category" option in the Permalink Settings.

Now my product URLs are like that:

> site.com/shop/category1/product1

However, this URL also goes to product1:

> site.com/shop/randomword/product1

There is no category such "randomword" and also site.com/shop/randomword/ gives 404 error but the URL above works. It does not redirect to /category1/product1, it just works.

Therefore `remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );`  is not working. It works for other posts but not products.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: You'd probably get better answers if you deleted this here and instead asked on [wordpress.se]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

The page works with a random category URL. So when the URL is not equal to permalink I decide to redirect to permalink. So when there is a random URL, it redirects to actual URL.

```
<?php 
     global $wp;
     $current_url = home_url( $wp->request );
     $actual_url = get_permalink();
     if ((is_product()) && ($current_url !== $actual_url)) {
         wp_redirect( $actual_url, 301 );
         exit();
} ?>
```

You can put this code in the header.php

When you enter

> site.com/shop/randomword/product1

it redirects to

> site.com/shop/category1/product1

**Edit:**

The code breaks the draft preview. Need to specify it is published.

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( $wp->request );
$actual_url = get_permalink();
$current_post_status = get_post_status();
if ((is_product()) && ($current_post_status == 'publish' ) && ($current_url !== $actual_url)) {
   wp_redirect( $actual_url, 301 );
   exit();
}
```